# install Azure client on ubuntu virtual machine public key is not available

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am following this link to install Azure client on a Ubuntu virtual machine on Azure. This virtual machine is probably on a private network and behind a firewall.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest

I have tried

```
    curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
```

and got this error:

```
    The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

And also tried Manual install instructions and this gives the same error on the first command

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

Then I googled the error and tried this:

```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

This gives me:

```
    Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.weXEf8jZ7m/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
    gpg: keyserver receive failed: End of file
```

And also tried this:

```
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
```

And got this:

```
    sudo: unable to resolve host -0: Bad message
    Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.DTxXTpZKKN/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
    gpg: key EB3E94ADBE1229CF: 6 signatures not checked due to missing keys
    gpg: key EB3E94ADBE1229CF: "Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>" not changed
    gpg: Total number processed: 1
    gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

I then rerun the sudo apt-get update but received the same error as before.

Comment: You mean the Networking settings of the VM? My account doesn't allow me to view that setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just 2 days before and asked the same question too. I have found the solution btw and here it is:

---

Okay, after much research I found out that the problem existed only on certain Nvidia Images and not on the barebone Linux images. So I figured that there must be something wrong with the trusted key itself. So, these are the steps that I did in order to fix the issue.

---

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Now you will be able to update the instance

---

Resources:
[1] http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=130558

---

Comment: "Use of apt-key is deprecated, except for the use of apt-key del in maintainer scripts to remove existing keys from the main keyring. If such usage of apt-key is desired the
       additional installation of the GNU Privacy Guard suite (packaged in gnupg) is required."  The new way is with [signed-by= in apt source list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_installation)